# DropDownList automatically appending items

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

In my markup I have defined a drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlFoo" />
```

In my `Page_Load()` event I have the code:

```
for (int i =0; i < 3; i++){
ddlFoo.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
}
```

My problem is, that if there is a post back, and the page reloads, it simply appends the new list items onto the existing set, making the dropdownlist's contents look like {0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2} for 3 page loads (one initial load with two postbacks).

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Should do the trick

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    for (int i =0; i < 3; i++){
        ddlFoo.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
    }
}
```